# How does the OS know what files to start first?

Tags: operating-system

I can't figure out how the OS knows what files to start first... Like how does it know to run the script which lets you login, instead of another random file. How is the file executed on bootup specified?

Answer (score 0):

It's a program. It can contain names of other program(s) to execute when needed and in whatever order desired. It can also take that information from a file. I see no conceptual problem here.

Comment: what program specifies which files get started?